# When my Google account is deactivated/expires, will my phone delete/lock my apps?

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, google-apps

**Short version:** I'm afraid my Android (HTC One M8) will freak out and delete/lock all the apps connected to my soon-to-be-deactivated Google account.

**Long version:** So my college email ("Account 1") is being deactivated next week (yay graduation!), and I want to make sure I'm taking all the right steps to save all my data (emails, Chrome stuff, Maps, apps, etc.). I created a new Gmail account ("Account 2") to transfer everything into. I've browsed the forums, and everyone says it's impossible to transfer Google Play Store data between accounts. However, I didn't find any discussions about what happens if my downloaded/purchased apps are connected to a DEACTIVATED account.

Most of the discussions I found talked about having multiple accounts on the same phone, and how Account 2 can still use apps downloaded/purchased by (still-active) Account 1 on the same phone. No problemo. However, I don't have this luxury, because my Account 1 will cease to exist next week.

**My question is this:** If I change my phone's primary account to Account 2 without removing Account 1, but then Account 1 ceases to exist in one week, will my phone freak out and automatically delete and/or lock all the apps that were purchased/downloaded by Account 1? Can I keep updating those apps after the expiration? And will it make any difference if I disable all of Account 1's syncing so that my phone "can't tell" that the account got deactivated?

Thanks for all your help!!